# How to export an Iframe to another website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am creating a website, where the user can create objects.
The objects are then stored in a list.
The user can see the list of created objects.

The div #object_list has to put in an iframe and embedded in another website. And the other website has to show only that list.
I know that iframe I can import content from another website, but in my case I would like to export content to another website and I would like to show only that div.
How can I achieve that?

```
   <div id="list_objects_container">
        <button id="list_objects_btn" class="btn btn-primary"
            onclick="manageObjects_obj.viewObj()">View</button>

        <!-- CONTAINER LIST-->
        <div id="object_list">

        </div>
       </div>
```

---

I tried doing this but in this way it shows all the website and I don't want that. I want only to show the objects list.

This what I would like to export to another website.

```
 <iframe style="border: none" src="http://myurl" width="100%"
            height="500" allowfullscreen sandbox>

       <div id="object_list">

        </div>

        </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about how iframes get content.

If you want an iframe to show an HTML document with a div in it, then:

1. Create an HTML document with a div in it
2. Publish that HTML document on a server.
3. Put the URL to that document in the `src` attribute of the iframe

---

Don't put a `<div>` between `<iframe>` and `</iframe>`. The content model of iframes is [Nothing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-content-nothing). All the content comes from the `src` attribute.

Comment: oh! thank you. So if I create a route like: myurl/viewobjects, and I put that as src, then it works with the thing I would like to do, correct?

Comment: Sounds right! (y)